# Term for Production Rollback

Tags: version-control, terminology, production, backups

The firm I work at keeps a copy of the compiled source code on production.

So basically on our Production server, we have two folders:

```
ProductionServer\SourceCode\

ProductionServer\SourceCodeRollback\
```

The Rollback folder always contains one version older code. This is done so that on deployment nights, if something is wrong with the new code, the deployer(who is not familiar with source control software) has the older version to revert back to.

My question is: Is there an official computer science term/nomenclature for the Rollback folder? Or is "Rollback" itself the official term?

Comment: "official"?  Who defines "Official"?

Comment: "Ass saver"?  That's the term I was taught anyway.

Comment: _"...the deployer(who is not familiar with source control software)..."_ this is scary enough that I would not care what the directory is called, and be more concerned with getting someone competent to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call ours the `revert` state. We have 2 scripts called `go_staging` and `go_production` that do the obvious things, with `go_production` making a fully functional revert state before anything else is done. We use to call our third script `go_revert` but we realized that it was better called `OMFG`. It's only been run twice (not counting testing), but it's allowed us to go from a `go_production` to "OMFG!" to a running site in something less than about 20 seconds round trip.

I love single-scripts-that-do-everything because when it hits the fan you normally aren't thinking too coherently.

Answer (score 2):

Does it really matter if there's a "proper" term? If it gets the point across, that's all that *really* matters.

Having said that, I'd either:

1. Get the "deployer" up to speed with at least the basics of source control. I'd be a little concerned with someone who couldn't grasp the fundamentals, whether they're a seasoned engineer or the building janitor.
2. Write a deployment/rollback script for the "deployer" to use that uses branches in source control to deploy.

Both of the above options are preferred (to me anyway) to storing an old version on the live server.